# Realtek-NIC with VLAN under Windows always showing UNPLUGGED

Tags: windows, windows-7, vlan, network-adapter, cable

I'm running a Win7-Machine and need to configure my NIC to understand untagged and VLAN-tagged packages. I'm using a `Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller` and already installed a common tagged VLAN-adapter with the Realtek-Diagnostics-Tool.
My NIC-Adapter-Overview in Windows shows up 3 NICs:

1. Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
2. (deactivated) Realtek RTL8139/810x Family Fast Ethernet
3. Realtek Virtual Miniport Driver for VLAN

The first adapter has IP4 enabled with correct settings and behavios as it should. The second one has all settings unmarked and is itself deactivated. The last one is the virtual one installed by the diag-tool and tagged with the correct VLAN-Number. So sad - it always shows `cable unplugged`. I can not use this adapter - but of course it has IP4-Settings enabled...  Any ideas?

Comment: "Realtek" <-- Found the problem. Not trying to be too much of a smart mass, but they're know for making *incredibly cheap* chips that, under *ideal circumstance*, when the planets are properly aligned, *usually* work. I expect them to break when doing anything complicated.

Comment: @ChrisS thank you - you might be right - but I need to use this device...

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? If so, please post as an answer?

Comment: @Arjan - sorry - no, I never found a solution for that. Else I would have posted here, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have VirtualBox installed try to uncheck VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver from all connections on that NIC. It is an issue described [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7094).